# set Input value using Jade template locals

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I want to set input value in my user profile to its db values if they are exists. I tried to use parameter passing in jade for this but I got the following error:

```
referenceError: /Users/Feras/Sites/wowito/views/profile.jade:13
    11|         fieldset(data-role='controlgroup') 
    12|          label.label(for='email')  EMail
  > 13|          input.input(id='email',type='text',value=email,name='email') 
    14|          label.label(for='firstName')  First Name
    15|          input.input(id='firstName',type='text',value='',name='firstName') 
    16|          label.label(for='lastName')  Last Name

email is not defined
```

but when I render this templat I send it email as locals

```
res.redirect('/profile',{locals :{email:"profile.email"}});
```

I tried also to set input value to !{email} and #{email} but nothing works. any help?

Thanks,
Feras

Answer (score 4, accepted):

res.redirect? res.render you mean? also you dont need locals:{}, just res.render('profile', { email: 'foo' })

Answer (score 3):

I found that I had to wrap my variables in single quotes or else I got a unexpected token error:

```
input.input(value='#{email}')
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use `#{ }` to access variables

```
input.input(id='email',type='text',value=#{email},name='email')
```